# Populating column map using Apache POI for dynamic columns

Tags: grails, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI plugin to read the column values, before I am using some dynamic values to compare the column names, and I am able to generate the column map values, and I am not able to get the correct format for the column names, If the column names are manually defined, the values get generated and if the values are generated using ASCII chars, fails to get the values.

From the below script till c Values gets generates, but furthers will not

code script is :

```
columnMap.put('C',zone)
char ch
for(int i=68; i < maxSize;i++){
    ch = (char)i
    String key1="'"
    String key2="'"
    String mainKey=key1+ch+key2
    columnMap.put(mainKey,attrList[i-68])
}
columnMap.put((char)maxSize,startDate)
```

Comment: Do you want something like "Column 0 = A, Column 2 = C" ?

Comment: Yes, I need to have multiple dynamically created cells..

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI provides a handy helper class for you to do this kind of translation, [CellReference](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html).

There's even a handy static method to quickly turn a 0-based column index (eg 3) into the column string label (eg D), [convertNumToColString(int col)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertNumToColString%28int%29)

All you need to do is [call that method](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertNumToColString%28int%29) with your column number, and you'll get back the reference